# Firebase database data retrieving

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

`I am retrying data from "News" as shown in screen shot and with the same procedure I am trying to retrieve from"Info" but in android it is showing data from news but not from info I have tried a lot, but I am unable to solve this please help.

[image: The screen shot is here.]

I'm doing like this:

```
DatabaseReference mInfo= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Info");
DatabaseReference mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("News");
```

It is working for news, but not for info.

code is here `

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
    import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
    import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    
    import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
    import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
    import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
    
    /**
     * Created by HP INDIA on 08-Apr-17.
     */

public  class FragmentOne extends Fragment  {
    public FragmentOne() {}
    private RecyclerView mInfoLists;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_one, container, false);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mInfoLists=(RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.mInfoLists);
    mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Info");
        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        linearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mInfoLists.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mInfoLists.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
        mInfoLists.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        mInfoLists.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_AUTO);
        mInfoLists.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OrgInfo,OrgInfoViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter=new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<OrgInfo,OrgInfoViewHolder>(
                OrgInfo.class,
                R.layout.home_list_item,
                OrgInfoViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase
        ){


            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(OrgInfoViewHolder viewHolder, OrgInfo model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDescription());
            }
        };
    mInfoLists.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
            return rootView;
        }

    public static class OrgInfoViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        View mView;
        public OrgInfoViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView=itemView;
        }


        public void setTitle(String title) {
            TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc) {
            TextView post_title=(TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.address);
            post_title.setText(desc);
        }
    }
```

`

This is how I am showing data. For news section the code is working and for info it's not

Comment: This code is not reading from the database yet. Please make sure your question includes the [minimum code needed to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I have edited the code please have look and help.